# Can I install Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot

I have HP Pavilion G4 Core i3 notebook with 6 GB RAM and 750 GB Hard Disk.
I have 2 Windows with dual booting Mode windows 7 and windows 8.

1. My question is that 
   Am I install Ubuntu on my system as a third operating with triple booting system or not.
2. Am I delete the windows 8 from the booting menu and from the system and replace with Ubuntu but the dual booting is not going to disturb.

I hope I find some answer.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on if your machine will accept 3 boots, the only way to find out is to do some research on your machine or trial and error.  Easiest thing to do is boot from a Ubuntu live CD or USB and try and install alongside your other operating systems.  If it does not let you then you will have to delete one of your Windows operating systems to enable you to use Ubuntu, alternativly you could try installing Ubuntu on an external hard drive if your just wanting to experiment with it just be aware if you take this route you will encounter slower read/write speeds.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install Ubuntu. The only thing you need is enough free space on your hard drive. If you don't have an empty space (non-partitioned), you'll need to resize one (or two) windows partitions. Ubuntu will detect Windows 7 & 8 during installation and it will put them, alongside Ubuntu on the boot menu. If you don't feel comfortable resizing partitions, you should ask someone else to do it for you. In case it isn't a problem for you to delete win7/8, you can let Ubuntu overwrite one of them.